# maya, python, naming obj by material's name

Tags: python, object, maya, scene

I want to name my objects in scene with name of theirs materials. If I try this, it works fine:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
allMat = cmds.ls(mat=True)
for mat in allMat:
    if (mat == "WriteMaterialName"): 
        SG = cmds.listConnections('%s.outColor' % mat)
        shapes = cmds.listConnections(SG, type="mesh")
        if ((shapes == None) or (shapes == "None") or (shapes == "") or (shapes == [])): continue 
        for shape in shapes:
            cmds.rename(shape, "Name")
```

but with all materials is not:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
allMat = cmds.ls(mat=True)
for mat in allMat:
    SG = cmds.listConnections('%s.outColor' % mat)
    shapes = cmds.listConnections(SG, type="mesh")
    if ((shapes == None) or (shapes == "None") or (shapes == "") or (shapes == [])): continue 
    for shape in shapes:
        cmds.rename(shape, "Name")
```

It rename some objects, not all. And writes this:

```
Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 12: No object matches name #
```

Comment: Try to find out where exactly the problem occurs. Insert a print() before the cmds and see where it stops.

Comment: I solved this:
        allMat = cmds.ls(mat=True)
    for mat in allMat:
        SG = cmds.listConnections('%s.outColor' % mat)
        shapes = cmds.listConnections(SG, type="mesh")
        if ((shapes == None) or (shapes == "None") or (shapes == "") or (shapes == [])): continue 
    i=0
    for i in range(len(shapes)): #<---this
        cmds.rename(shapes[i], "Name")
        shapes = cmds.listConnections(SG, type="mesh")#<---and this
        i+=1

Comment: You code in the comment is unreadable, you should either add it to your original question or add an answer so we can see the result. Just in case you are interested: Since listConnections() always return a list, you can completely remove the if() line and it makes no difference.